# Sharing DB Access Methods between Client and Server in Entity Framework (C#.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, architecture, client-server

it's a kind of client-server architecture problem.

I have 2 projects in my solution: one project for the client side working with Entity Framework and SQL Server Compact database and another one for the server side also working with Entity Framework but with a real SQL Server database. Both databases have exactly the same database schema, so although  they are using different .edmx files, the generated entities looks the same and only differ in namespaces. By the way I'm using the ADO.NET DbContext Generator to generate persistence ignorant entity classes. So far so good. Now I wrote a (quite large) class with all the server database access methods inside, e.g.:

```
    public User CreateUser(string userId, string username, bool isGlobalAdmin)
    {
        using (var context = new ServerEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                var user = new User
                {
                    UserID = userId,
                    Username = username,
                    IsGlobalAdmin = isGlobalAdmin
                };

                context.User.Add(user);
                context.SaveChanges();

                return user;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HandleEfException(ex);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

The problem is that I need the same class with the same methods on the client side. So I would copy this class to the client project, rename ServerEntities into ClientEntities and change the namespace for using client entities. This is quite ugly, because I need to maintain both classes, if something changes. Is there a way to abstract the whole thing and use the same class (which is located in a separate prject the other two projects refer to) on both sides (client and server)?

I would really appreciate your help.

Best,

Antony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the databases are guaranteed to be identical, why do you need both sets of entities? Just use one set so they are interoperable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, David. I was not sure if it is even possible for my scenario, but it worked. I created a separate project with all the generated entities inside. I also wrote my own DbContext class instead of using the auto-generated one. This project also contains my class with all the database actions. In the constructor of  this class I can choose between server and client, so all the methods are using the right connection string for the certain database. It works like a charm :) Thanks again, David!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
#if SERVER
    using (var context = new ServerEntities())
#elif CLIENT
    using (var context = new ClientEntities())
#endif
```

Then, in the project properties for both projects, under Build and then the Conditional Compliation Symbols box, you can add the token for each. So, in the server project, add `SERVER`and in the client, add `CLIENT`. If there are already tokens there, separate with semicolon (`;`).

Whichever project you put the class in, add it as a link to the second project. For instance, if the class file lives in the server project, in the client project, go to Add -> Existing item. Select the file, but then click the arrow by `Open` and click "Add as Link". This will ensure there is only one copy linked to both projects.

When each is compiled, the compiler will look at the tokens, evaluate them, and it will use the `ClientEntities` line in the Client project and the `ServerEntities` in the Server project.

You can do the same preprocessor directives for namespaces if needed. Here is [an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) explaining the directives.

Comment: Antony, I see you are a brand new user. If this answers your question, please select the green check mark beside it to accept the answer.